# Notepad++ Zen Coding : Print $ (dollar sign)

Tags: notepad++, dollar-sign, emmet

I'm using N++ with Zen Coding. And now i want to make a shortkey. Usually I edit the ZenCoding.js, But when I tried to print Dollar sign, it failed.

My question is, how to print dollar sign, with Npp Zend coding?

Example:
When I type "po", and then I "Expand Abbreviation", it becomes "$_POST[]".

Answer (score 1):

To create a short key for Zen Coding (Emmet) with a dollar, use `$|` (dollar pipe).

Answer (score 0):

$ sign stands for:

```
Item numbering with $ character: li.item$*3 will output <li> tag three times, replacing $ character with item number.
Multiple '$' characters in a row are used as zero padding, i.e.: li.item$$$ → li.item001
```

How about using `&#36;` istead of `$`?

Comment: I've tried using dec and hex value, and it works for all symbol except dollar sign. Using &#36 doesn't work because it is not escaped to any character.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has haunted me for years. And the solution is counter-intuitive.
To write the dollar sign in the text, put the dollar sign followed by a pipe character.

```
$|
```

It's counterintuitive because we learned that the pipe character serves to indicate the cursor position after autocompletion occurs. But in this particular case, the pipe character "post escapes" the dollar sign.
I don't know why this is so.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This answer, while well-written, does appear to have already been covered in another answer.